# Calibri not appearing in font-family

Tags: css, fonts, styles, webfonts

I am trying to use calibri as a font-family in my css. I am using Mac and calibri.ttf is stored in the Font-file from Mac. Somehow Css doesnt show calibri in the dropdown list.
Where could the problem be?

I have tried several things:

```
font-family: calibri
font-family: "calibri"
font-family: calibri.ttf
```

Nothings working. Its not even in the list of the css suggestions (dropdown list)

Path: Macintosh HD/Library/Fonts

I am using coda

Comment: What does "stored in font file from Mac" mean?

Comment: Show us the whole file? font-family: "Calibri"; should work

Comment: What are you talking about with "css suggestions" and "Css doesnt show calibri in dropdown list"?  What dropdown list?

Comment: YOU and/or question are OP... Original Poster or Original Post.

Comment: Do you realize you can't just take a font from your local machine and put it on a public website for everyone else to see?  You would either have to use an [embedded font stored on a server someplace](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/05/03/understanding-and-using-embedded-fonts-what-why-and-how/) or just use a more common font that you know most people already have installed like Times, Verdana, etc.

Comment: Most users have calibri installed. (Vista and win7 users and Mac users who have office installed) For them it will work. A font face is not allowed for calibri because users, that dont have the font, might download it, which microsoft doesnt allow. I will provide some alternative fonts for users that dont have calibri installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibri is stored inside a Microsoft directory on the Mac -- 
Mac HDD/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Calibri.ttf.

As Sparky points out, you can't simply declare any font for use if this is intended for a web page to be hosted somewhere. Fonts need to be accessible from the internet and the font files on your Mac are not. In addition, font licenses may not permit you to use Calibri as a web font.

All that being posted, if a user has Calibri installed on their system then the font should work provided your CSS rules are correct.

To get Calibri working on your machine, you need to capitalize the name.

```
.class { font-family: Calibri, san-serif; }
```

The above CSS rule functions here on my Mac.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Although the problem was that I only needed to restart the computer and afterwards the font was recognised. But thanks again for a good answer.